# replicate Outlook behaviour in asp.net web forms filling toS emails

Tags: asp.net, web, webforms

In Outlook when you start typing in the "to" field, a combo appears with the matching addresses; For example, if I type "smi", then I see two names with their emails "John Smith jsmith@watever" and "Jenny jsmith@watever".

If my asp.net web app retrieves a list of names and their email address from a table, how can I replicate this behaviour ? Is there a dropdown that only shows the matching elements corresponding to the filter (the letters I could type in the textbox) * without * loading ALL the emails in the dropdown ?! Is there any already made, open source control available for this, for a 'fast' implementation ?

Thanks in advance,

Roger

Comment: hi Roger, although there are some good controls at the 'clientside' (bootstrap-select), they all need all data loaded upfront. Some time ago I build a customcontrol myself; it isn't perfect, but maybe you can make use of it. Send me an e-mail, and I'd be happy to mail you the source of this control: tim@kerkrade.net

Comment: Thanks Tim... I ended up by implementing a separate textbox to introduce the filter, and a button + dropdown to filter and show the results. That basic idea was accepted from the customer, so I don't worry anymore.